# Google sheets: Record date when selecting particular drop down

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to capture the date, or be asked to enter a date when selecting a particular drop down value?

For example, if a task is complete, when selecting "complete" from a dropdown list, I want the date captured for record in a different cell.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You would need to use a script for this rather than just formulae.

Answer (score 1):

We can add script in google sheet to track particular column activity.

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 1) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
            if (nextCell.getValue() === '') //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
                nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Refer:

[Capture Time Stamp Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vfi_NiwF1AC2kzqS_VwwnmXGFS5Jp-suqDojxZXrKZQ/edit?usp=sharing)